# How does one delete a concept using its ID (node gRCP client)

Tags: node.js, clarifai

I using Clarifai to *simplifai* custom model training for a client.
I want to expose the CRUD API for inputs, annotations and concepts.
I am unable to find how to delete concepts using the gRCP node client (V7.4)

**Please help me figure out how to delete concepts having only the concept's id**

There seems to be a way to delete concepts using inputs : https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/data/create-get-update-delete

The docs do not reveal how to delete concepts :
https://docs.clarifai.com/portal-guide/concept/concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean removing a concept completely from your app, that's not possible. A concept cannot be hard deleted yet in Clarifai.